# How to generate list objects within tidytable mutate rowwise?

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, tidytable

I have the following `want` table, which are generated with `rowwise()` and `mutate()`.
The main issue is that this solution is too slow.

The actual dataset contains around 15,000,000 rows, and took around 6 hours to complete.

What I hope to do is to convert the `rowwise()` and `mutate()` operations into tidytable so that it can leverage on `data.table` speed. Or maybe I just need a base R solution?

```
set.seed(1990)
mydf <- tibble(id = as.vector(outer(letters, letters, paste0))[1:10]
               , open_week = rep(1:5,2)) %>%
  mutate(close_week = open_week + sample(1:5,10, replace = T)) %>%
  arrange(open_week)
mydf
# some are closed, some are not closed # if not closed, set to NA
mydf$close_week[sample(c(TRUE, FALSE),10, replace = T, prob = c(0.1,0.9))] <- NA


mydf

# A tibble: 10 x 3
   id    open_week close_week
   <chr>     <int>      <int>
 1 aa            1          2
 2 fa            1          4
 3 ba            2          4
 4 ga            2         NA
 5 ca            3          7
 6 ha            3          6
 7 da            4          6
 8 ia            4          5
 9 ea            5          7
10 ja            5          9

# calculate up to the last week
week_last <- max(mydf$close_week, na.rm = T)

# create complete week grid
df <- as_tibble(data.frame(week = seq(from = min(mydf$open_week, na.rm = T)
                                     , to = max(mydf$close_week, na.rm = T), by = 1)))

have <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate( # which IDs are active - for the rowwise week?
         active_id_list = list(mydf$id[week >= mydf$open_week & 
                                                          week < ifelse(is.na(mydf$close_week),
                                                                        week_last +1,
                                                                        mydf$close_week)]),
         # what are the ages of the IDs - for the rowwise week?
         active_id_age_list = list(week - mydf$open_week[week >= mydf$open_week & 
                                                            week < ifelse(is.na(mydf$close_week),
                                                                                   week +1,
                                                                          mydf$close_week)]),
         # which IDs have age less than 1 week, more than 1 week - for the rowwise week?
         active_id_less_1_week_list = list(active_id_list[active_id_age_list < 1]),
         active_id_above_1_week_list = list(active_id_list[active_id_age_list >= 1]),
         
         # how many active IDs based on age less than 1 week, age more than 1 week - for the rowwise week?
         active_id_less_1_week = sum(active_id_age_list < 1, na.rm = T),
         active_id_above_1_week = sum(active_id_age_list >= 1, na.rm = T),

         # how many active IDs in total?
         active_id_count = length(active_id_age_list)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::select(!where(is.list)) # remove the list object, unless want to inspect the actual ID list

have

# A tibble: 9 x 4
   week active_id_less_1_week active_id_above_1_week active_id_count
  <dbl>                 <int>                  <int>           <int>
1     1                     2                      0               2
2     2                     2                      1               3
3     3                     2                      3               5
4     4                     2                      3               5
5     5                     2                      4               6
6     6                     0                      4               4
7     7                     0                      2               2
8     8                     0                      2               2
9     9                     0                      1               1
```

I tried replacing the `rowwise()` and `mutate()` with `tidytable::mutate_rowwise.()`
as per https://markfairbanks.github.io/tidytable/reference/mutate_rowwise..html

But I'm not sure how to interpret the following error

```
have <- df %>% 
  tidytable::mutate_rowwise.( # which IDs are active - for the rowwise week?
    active_id_list = list(mydf$id[week >= mydf$open_week & 
                                    week < ifelse(is.na(mydf$close_week),
                                                  week_last +1,
                                                  mydf$close_week)]),
    # what are the ages of the IDs - for the rowwise week?
    active_id_age_list = list(week - mydf$open_week[week >= mydf$open_week & 
                                                      week < ifelse(is.na(mydf$close_week),
                                                                    week +1,
                                                                    mydf$close_week)]),
    # which IDs have age less than 1 week, more than 1 week - for the rowwise week?
    active_id_less_1_week_list = list(active_id_list[active_id_age_list < 1]),
    active_id_above_1_week_list = list(active_id_list[active_id_age_list >= 1]),
    
    # how many active IDs based on age less than 1 week, age more than 1 week - for the rowwise week?
    active_id_less_1_week = sum(active_id_age_list < 1, na.rm = T),
    active_id_above_1_week = sum(active_id_age_list >= 1, na.rm = T),
    
    # how many active IDs in total?
    active_id_count = length(active_id_age_list)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::select(!where(is.list)) # remove the list object, unless want to inspect the actual ID list

Error in `[.data.table`(list(week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), .rowwise_id = 1:9),  : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Comment: @akrun ah thanks, updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs in subsetting the `list` element i.e. we are not extracting the `list` element.  It can be done with `[[`

```
df %>% 
  tidytable::mutate_rowwise.( # which IDs are active - for the rowwise week?
    active_id_list = list(mydf$id[week >= mydf$open_week & 
                                    week < ifelse(is.na(mydf$close_week),
                                                  week_last +1,
                                                  mydf$close_week)]),
    # what are the ages of the IDs - for the rowwise week?
    active_id_age_list = list(week - mydf$open_week[week >= mydf$open_week & 
                                                      week < ifelse(is.na(mydf$close_week),
                                                                    week +1,
                                                                    mydf$close_week)]), active_id_less_1_week_list = list(active_id_list[active_id_age_list[[1]] < 1]))
```

Comment: Thanks, however, it seems the performance in speed is almost negligible.  Guess it has to do with the `rowwise` step as you mentioned earlier... Not sure whether this will be still within the scope of this question, but I definitely need alternatives to this `rowwise` step.

Comment: @AfiqJohari I would use `map` or `pmap` etc from `purrr` to speed up

Comment: I'm already using registerDoParallel for parallelization, on 2 cores currently.

Comment: @AfiqJohari Or may be `foreach` would be better.  When I have some performance issues, I switch to `foreach`

Comment: yes, specifically I'm also using `foreach` `%dopar%`, maybe a complete rewrite of the rowwise step into base R would do I guess.

Comment: I would use `foreach` without the `rowwise`

Comment: I see, I understand what you mean. thanks @akrun. I'm actually using the `foreach` to loop over a series of values. Where each value would generate its own `rowwise` step. It's ok, I'll explore a bit more, and probably create a new question.